# `BatchStatement` occasionally gets data out of sync

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax

"Cassandra: The Definitive Guide, 2nd Edition" says:

> Cassandra’s batches are a good fit for use cases such as making
>   multiple updates to a single partition, or keeping multiple tables in
>   sync. A good example is making modifications to denormalized tables
>   that store the same data for different access patterns.

The last statement above applies to the following attempt, where all the `Save...` are `insert` statements for different tables

```
var bLogged = new BatchStatement();
var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
var uuidNow = TimeUuid.NewId(now);

bLogged.Add(SaveMods.Bind(id, uuidNow, data1));                      // 1
bLogged.Add(SaveMoreMods.Bind(id, uuidNow, data2));                  // 2
bLogged.Add(SaveActivity.Bind(now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), id, now)); // 3

await GetSession().ExecuteAsync(bLogged);
```

We'll focus on statements 1 and 2 (the 3rd one is just to signify there's one more statement in the batch).

Statement 1 writes to table1 partitioned by `id` with `uuidNow` being a clustering key `desc`.
Statement 2 writes to table2 partitioned by `id` only, so it's the *tip* of the table1 for the same `id`.

More times than I'd like the two tables get out of sync in the sense that `table2` does not have the *tip* of the `table1`. It would be one or two mods *behind* within a few milliseconds.

While looking for resolution most on the web advise  against all batches, which prompted my solution eliminating all mismatches:

```
await Task.WhenAll(
    GetSession().ExecuteAsync(SaveMods.Bind(id, uuidNow, data1)),
    GetSession().ExecuteAsync(SaveMoreMods.Bind(id, uuidNow, data2)),
    GetSession().ExecuteAsync(SaveActivity.Bind(now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), id, now))
);
```

The question is: what are batches good for, just the first statement in the quote? In that case how do I ensure modifications to different tables are in sync?

Answer (score 1):

Using higher consistency (ie quorum) on reads/writes may help but there is always a possibility for inconsistencies between the table/partitions.

Batch statements will try to ensure that all the mutations in the batch will all happen or not. It does not guarantee that all the mutations will occur in an instant (no isolation, you can do a read where first mutation has been applied but others haven't). Also, batch statements will not provide a consistent view of all the data across all the nodes. For linearizable consistency you should consider using paxos (lightweight transactions) for conditional updates and trying to limit things that require the linearizability into a single partition.

Comment: Actually, in this case I'd be satisfied with consistency `Any` as I don't need it back right away. The problem is that even after some time (hours) the discrepancy exists. Meaning, that a write to the "log-type" `table1` succeeded, whereas "tip-row" `table2` apparently failed with no such indication. And these discrepancies keep accumulating.